# sql server query performance issues

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a table that has columns of

- non-unique id
- n-columns of various data

a date of when data was updated

I have a query that, given a date range, it gets the list of entries that were updated during that date range and the entry of the last update prior to the one it just found.  Generally the date range is within a day so 07-10-2013 00:00:000 - 7-11-2013 00:00:000.

eg. given 07-10-2013 00:00:000 - 7-11-2013 00:00:000, the query found 2 entries

```
id   new data      updatedate              old data     last updatedate
3    randomdata    7-10-2013 03:30:343     randomdata   7-05-2013 06:34:764
4    randomdata    7-10-2013 13:30:343     randomdata   6-09-2013 04:37:376
```

This is the result i would like to get. Currently I already have a query that does this but the query is slow because there are 3 inner joins on a table that has a lot of entries and I was wondering if anyone could think of a way to make the query faster. Using SQL Server 2000.

Table Info

- non-unique ID
- unique id (this is just an auto increment id)
- various data to be collected
- updated date

Edit:

Indexes are currently on `id` and `updatedate`

Query I'm currently using (generalizing it) **::WARNING::***It's not pretty***::WARNING::**

```
select * 
from 
    (select distinct 
        s1.id as id, 
        s1.randData1, s2.randData1, s1.randData2, s2.randData2,..., 
        s1.updatedate as newupdatedate,
        s2.updatedate as prevupdatedate, 
        datediff(second, s1.updatedate ,s2.updatedate) as maxdate 
     from 
        (select * 
         from updates 
         where updatedate >= '{0}' and updatedate < '{1}' 
           and id in ('{3}')) as s1 
     inner join 
        updates s2 on s1.id = s2.id and s1.updateid != s2.updateid) as t1 
 inner join 
     (select 
          s1.id, max(datediff(second, s1.updatedate, s2.updatedate)) as maxdate2 
      from updates s1 
      inner join updates s2 on s1.id in ('{3}') and s1.id = s2.id and s1.updateid != s2.updateid 
      where datediff(second, s1.updatedate, s2.updatedate) < 0
        and s1.updatedate < '{1}' and s2.updatedate < '{1}' 
      group by 
         s1.id) as t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.maxdate = t2.maxdate2
```

The {0} {1} and {2} are params passed in.

Edit: The query is being executed in C# if that makes any difference.  If necessary, 2 queries would be good too.  What i'm ultimately looking for is what changed in the data on the selected date.

Comment: Could you post the query and tell us what indexes are in place?

Answer (score 0):

I have had pretty good luck getting all those nested select statements into #Temp Tables.  Depending on how big you are really talking you could possibly use table variables.

Could also double check your query step by step to see if you really need to carry all that data long in each nested query.  In otherwords does all the nested queries get consumed by the outer query or is extra data coming over.

I think with the complexity seen here using temp tables would be your best bet.  That way all your nested queries can build the temp table instead of having to hold them in memory.

Your final query would be much more compact and much quicker.

Comment: The 1st inner query that does the distinct randData is the data i'm looking for and the the 2nd maxdate2 is used for finding the entry of the date previous to the one selected.  I've tried to limit as much as possible of what to inner join as my knowledge of Sql performance is low.  I figured if the 1st outer table had the minimal amount of entries, then the outer inner join would be quicker.  Hope that's not too confusing.

Comment: Just have multiple statements.  Get your nested select statements set up in some real tables and then truncate them at the end when you are all done.  That way you only have one select statement and it is looking back to tables on the disk not in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use temp tables -

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #temp

SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM dbo.updates
WHERE ID IN ('{3}')

SELECT * 
FROM 
    (
     SELECT DISTINCT 
             s1.id AS id, 
             s1.randData1, s2.randData1, s1.randData2, s2.randData2,
             s1.updatedate AS newupdatedate,
             s2.updatedate AS prevupdatedate, 
             DATEDIFF(second, s1.updatedate ,s2.updatedate) AS maxdate 
     FROM 
     (
          SELECT *
          FROM #temp
          WHERE updatedate BETWEEN '{0}' AND '{1}'
     ) s1 
     JOIN #temp s2 ON s1.id = s2.id AND s1.updateid != s2.updateid
) t1 
JOIN (
     SELECT 
          s1.id, 
          MAX(DATEDIFF(second, s1.updatedate, s2.updatedate)) AS maxdate2 
     FROM #temp s1 
     JOIN #temp s2 ON s1.id = s2.id AND s1.updateid != s2.updateid 
     WHERE DATEDIFF(second, s1.updatedate, s2.updatedate) < 0
          AND s1.updatedate < '{1}' AND s2.updatedate < '{1}' 
     GROUP BY s1.id
) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.maxdate = t2.maxdate2
```

Comment: Problem with this is i'm running the query within C# so I'm not absolutely sure if this will work or not since there are 2 select statements.  Sorry, I probably should have added that to the original post.